# How to work out this vector question

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $a = (-2,0,0)$ and $b = (-1,2,2)$

What is $|a|^2|b|^2+|a⋅b|^2$

This is what I have for now:

- $|a|^2 = 2^2$ because the magnitude of $a$ is $2$
- $|b|^2 = 3^2$ because the magnitude of $b$ is $3$

This is where I'm more confused

- the dot product of $a$ and $b$ is $(-2)\cdot(-1)$ so $|a⋅b|^2$ is $|2|^2 = 4$?

So $4 \cdot 9 + 4 = 40$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly are $i,j,k$ and what is $x$ supposed to be?

Comment: @StiftungWarentest I'm sorry I thought it was just another way of writing a vector?

Comment: So $i,j,k$ is the standard basis? but then what is $x$

Comment: @StiftungWarentest what is x? like I don't know what you mean

Comment: I mean the $x$ in "the dot product of a and b is 2 (-2x-1)"

Comment: Anyways if I understood you question correctly then $a = -2i = (-2,0,0)$ and $b = -i+2j+2k = (-1,2,2)$ and then indeed $a\cdot b = (-1)\cdot (-2) = 2$ as you said. Note however that your notation doesn't work. You either write $b = -i+2j+2k$ or $b = (-1,2,2)$, not a mixture of both

Comment: @StiftungWarentest oh! I'm sorry the 'x' was meant to be the multiplication sign. Thanks for letting me know my notation was wrong, this is my first time learning vectors. So since my concern was in fact correct, does that mean my answer was right? but my notation was not?

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct, but the notation isn't.

Comment: The multiplication symbol is '\times' ($\times$), or '\cdot' ($\cdot$). See the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).